# Oracle: Limiting a join with a 'many' table to just one instance?

Tags: oracle, join

This query returns a wide table containing horse-race results. However, one horse has multiple trainers and so this join is returning the same race-result for each trainer the horse has. How do I work around this? I've been playing around with Group By but Oracle doesn't seem to like it.

```
SELECT 
    b.meet_name AS Course, 
    a.race_time AS Time, 
    (f.jf_name||' '||f.jl_name) AS Jockey,     
    e.horse_name AS Horse, 
    c.odds, 
    d.place, 
    d.race_comment AS Note, 
    (g.bf_name||' '||g.bl_name) AS Breeder, 
    (h.tf_name||' '||h.tl_name) AS Trainer, 
    a.race_type AS Type, 
    a.distance AS     Furlongs, 
    a.prize_money AS "Prize Money", 
    a.ground AS Ground
    FROM proj_race_details a
    JOIN proj_meet b ON a.meet_id = b.meet_id
    JOIN proj_entry c ON c.race_id = a.race_id
    JOIN proj_results d ON d.race_id = c.race_id AND d.horse_id = c.horse_id
    JOIN proj_horses e ON e.horse_id = d.horse_id
    JOIN proj_jockey f ON f.jockey_id = d.jockey_id
    JOIN proj_breeder g ON g.breeder_id = e.breeder_id
    JOIN proj_trainer h ON h.trainer_id = e.trainer_id;
```

Comment: Do you want the trainer information in the results? If not, you can simply drop the join with the proj_trainer table, right? Also, the last result column is incomplete (e.?)

Comment: I want one trainer to return, but never more than one. Yeah, you can ignore the incomplete e. thing, I just forget to finish that bit.

Comment: How would you select which trainer to include in the result? Only the first trainer, with the trainer names sorted alphabetically?

Comment: I'd be happy include any of the trainers as long as it was just one of them. They all have unique identifiers though, so I'm unsure about using DISTINCT. The value being return for the trainer will be a NUMBER type. I should point out that in reality it is an un-posted variable "owner" which is the real problem", trainer actually works fine because it's one to one. I used trainer to illustrate the problem for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This query would select only one trainer per horse. The trainer's name would be the first one, sorted alphabetically.

```
SELECT 
    b.meet_name AS Course, 
    a.race_time AS Time, 
    (f.jf_name||' '||f.jl_name) AS Jockey,     
    e.horse_name AS Horse, 
    c.odds, 
    d.place, 
    d.race_comment AS Note, 
    (g.bf_name||' '||g.bl_name) AS Breeder, 
    h.Trainer, 
    a.race_type AS Type, 
    a.distance AS     Furlongs, 
    a.prize_money AS "Prize Money", 
    a.ground AS Ground
FROM proj_race_details a
JOIN proj_meet b ON a.meet_id = b.meet_id
JOIN proj_entry c ON c.race_id = a.race_id
JOIN proj_results d ON d.race_id = c.race_id AND d.horse_id = c.horse_id
JOIN proj_horses e ON e.horse_id = d.horse_id
JOIN proj_jockey f ON f.jockey_id = d.jockey_id
JOIN proj_breeder g ON g.breeder_id = e.breeder_id
JOIN 
(SELECT ph.horse_id AS horse_id, MIN(pj.tf_name||' '||pj.tl_name) AS Trainer
FROM proj_trainer pj INNER JOIN proj_horses ph
ON pj.trainer_id = ph.trainer_id
GROUP BY ph.horse_id
) h
ON h.horse_id = e.horse_id;
```